# Creating a lua table in c++ function

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I've written a function in C++ which is getting 'items' inside container. I need to put those variables in table, but anything I do, script is always overwriting first cell of table.
Im using Lua 5.0

```
Container *box = dynamic_cast<Container*>(item);
        if(box)
        {

            lua_newtable(L);
            int top = lua_gettop(L);
            int n = box->lcontained.size();

            for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {  

                Item* karta = box->getItem(i);
                if(karta)
                {

                    setField(L,"slot", i);
                    setField(L,"kartaid", karta->getID());

                    lua_settop(L, top);

                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setField(L,"slot", i);
```

Remember: Lua used *one*-based indices. So in C++ code that talks to Lua, you too must use one-based indices. So you need `i+1`.